# jquery: image width on domready or load?

Tags: jquery, image, width

hey guys,
I'm using the jquery data() method to store the width of images.

When is jquery able to get the width of images. on-dom-ready or on-load?
Is it necessary to have the images loaded to query it's width, or can i query the width on domready as well?

thank you

this is my piece of code:

```
    //Save the original image width
    $(".post-body img").each(function() {  
        $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, if you're *specifying* the width, then DOM ready works fine.  If you're depending on the width coming from the image itself, you need to check once it's loaded, using `window.onload` which fires after images are loaded, for example:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var w = $("img").width();
});
```

Comment: As an additional note, if the image is already cached, some browsers will not call the `.load()` event.  After binding load, or setting the source, check the images `.complete` property and trigger the load event if it is true.

Comment: @Duncanmoo - you should re-read the answer, the entire point is the width is unknown and needs to be checked because post-render.  I agree on using width is all cases they're known, but that specifically *isn't* the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your images are coming in when the page loads and you are sure that none are going to be loaded after (as a result of ajax calls or something) Nick's answer will work fine. Otherwise, it is a bit tougher. Here is the event I bind to for image load event for such cases:

https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/pull/4#diff-0

It's still a work in progress since this is a tough problem...