# AJAX: get html and check if images has finished loading

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to load html and images in a specific container.
I need to animate the height of the enclosing container, so i tried:

```
// load content
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.get('content/'+id+'/html/content.html', function(data) {

    // insert html
    $('#overlay-inner').html(data);

    // show overlay
    $('#overlay').fadeIn();

    // add new height to wrapper
    var height = $('#overlay').height() + 200;
    console.log(height);
    $('#wrapper').animate({'height':height});

});
```

Unfortunately, it works only sometimes, cause the height isn't correct. The loaded data contains a few images and they need a little time to load.

Is there any method to check if all images are loaded, so i can animate the height after the complete loading?

Comment: slevin are you calling it on document.ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ImagesLoaded plugin:

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

See that page for an example.

The jQuery `$().load` won't work, as it doesn't fire when the images are already cached (see [jquery: image width on domready or load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461689/jquery-image-width-on-domready-or-load))

Comment: The answer suggests the opposite of what you are saying.

Comment: @Asad Right. Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Samuel I think that only applies to load handlers attached directly to images, not the window.